# Splitting a .gz file into specified file sizes in Java

Tags: java, split, gzip

This is my first posting, so not sure how apt my description of the issue is..

Below is a program I have written to split a .gz file into files based on the size of each file, the user wants. The parent .gz file is getting split, but not into the size as specified in the code.
For example, in the main I have said I want the parent file to be split into files of size 1 MB. But on executing the code, its getting split into n number of files of different sizes. Can someone help me pin point where I am going wrong? Any help would be great as I have run out of ideas..

```
package com.bitsighttech.collection.packaging;  


import java.io.BufferedReader;  
import java.io.DataInputStream;  
import java.io.File;  
import java.io.FileInputStream;  
import java.io.FileOutputStream;  
import java.io.InputStreamReader;  
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.List;  
import java.util.regex.Matcher;  
import java.util.regex.Pattern;  
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;  
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;  

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;  

public class FileSplitter   
{  
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FileSplitter.class);  
    private static final long KB = 1024;  
    private static final long MB = KB * KB;        

    public List<File> split(File inputFile, String splitSize)    
    {    
        int expectedNoOfFiles =0;         
        List<File> splitFileList = new ArrayList<File>();  
        try    
        {    
            double parentFileSizeInB = inputFile.length();  
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\s([MmGgKk][Bb])");  
            Matcher m = p.matcher(splitSize);  
            m.matches();  
            String FileSizeString = m.group(1);  
            System.out.println("FileSizeString----------------------"+FileSizeString);  
            String unit = m.group(2);  
            double fileSizeInMB = 0;  

            try {  
                if (unit.toLowerCase().equals("kb"))  
                    fileSizeInMB = Double.parseDouble(FileSizeString) / KB;           
                else if (unit.toLowerCase().equals("mb"))  
                    fileSizeInMB = Double.parseDouble(FileSizeString);                
                else if (unit.toLowerCase().equals("gb"))  
                    fileSizeInMB = Double.parseDouble(FileSizeString) * KB;           
            }   
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {  
                logger.error("invalid number [" + fileSizeInMB  + "] for expected file size");  
            }             
            System.out.println("fileSizeInMB----------------------"+fileSizeInMB);  
            double fileSize = fileSizeInMB * MB;  
            long fileSizeInByte = (long) Math.ceil(fileSize);  
            double noOFFiles = parentFileSizeInB/fileSizeInByte;   
            expectedNoOfFiles =  (int) Math.ceil(noOFFiles);  
            System.out.println("0000000000000000000000000"+expectedNoOfFiles);  
            GZIPInputStream in = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputFile));             
            DataInputStream datain = new DataInputStream(in);  
            BufferedReader fis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(datain));  
            int count= 0 ;  
            int splinterCount = 1;  
            GZIPOutputStream outputFileWriter = null;  
            while ((count = fis.read()) != -1)   
            {  
                System.out.println("count----------------------1 "+count);  
                int outputFileLength = 0;    
                outputFileWriter = new  GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("F:\\ff\\" + "_part_" + splinterCount + "_of_" + expectedNoOfFiles + ".gz"));  
                while (     (count = fis.read()) != -1   
                        &&  outputFileLength < fileSizeInByte  
                ) {    

                    outputFileWriter.write(count);    
                    outputFileLength ++;    
                    count = fis.read();  

                }  
                System.out.println("count----------------------2 "+count);  
                //outputFileWriter.finish();  
                outputFileWriter.close();  
                splinterCount ++;    
            }  
            fis.close();  
            datain.close();  
            in.close();  
            outputFileWriter.close();  
            System.out.println("Finished");  

        }catch(Exception e)    
        {    
            logger.error("Unable to split the file " + inputFile.getName() + " in to " + expectedNoOfFiles);  
            return null;  
        }    
        logger.debug("Successfully split the file [" + inputFile.getName() + "] in to " + expectedNoOfFiles + " files");  
        return splitFileList;  
    }      

    public static void main(String args[])   
    {  
        String filePath1 = "F:\\filename.gz";  
        File  file = new File(filePath1);  

        FileSplitter fileSplitter = new FileSplitter();  
        String splitlen = "1 MB";  
        int noOfFilesSplit = 3;  

        fileSplitter.split(file, splitlen);  

    }  
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do ? Are you trying to read a compressed file then read out its contents and try to create a n separate zip files (which is what it looks like) or you want one zip file split into multiple and then later join them to one ? (In which case, you dont have to read any content of zip file, but just split that original file)

Comment: I want to do the later Prajeesh.. I tried simply splitting the .gz file and then combining it..the trouble was that the re assembled file was in some encoded format which was not at all readable. So, I tried to read the original file, spplit it and then reassemble which is also failing..

Comment: If you look carefully, your inner while loop does the read two times, discarding the first read at the end of the while loop and then reading again in the while loops condition, thus loosing one byte for one byte. `while ((count = fis.read()) != -1` should be changed to `while (count!= -1`   and check with your original zip reading instead of reading the contents.

Answer (score 1):

Andreas' answer covers your main question, but there are a lot of problems in that code. Most importantly, you're throwing out one byte for each 'split' (the outer `while` calls fis.read() and ignores the value).

Why are you wrapping your gzip input stream in a DataInputStream *and* a BufferedReader if you're still reading it a byte at a time?

Edit

Ah, and you're also throwing out the *last* byte of each split, too (except for the very last one).

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell, but it looks to me like your counting the uncompressed bytes. The compressed chunks (resulting files) will be smaller.

Comment: true, but the thing is, the text of the parent file has also got distorted after splitting.. Plus, the parent file is 15 MB, which becomes 3 MB when compressed.

On using the split (File, String) function to split the .gz file, smaller files are getting created, but the data gets jumbled up.. Do you know why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

When you compress data with gzip the output file size depends on the complexity of data. Here you are compressing equally sized blocks, but their compressed sizes are different. No lossless compression algorithm reduces the size of input by a constant factor.

If you want splinters of equal size you should split the compressed data instead of decompressing first. But that of course means that the splinters have to be decompressed in order and you can't decompress one without reading the ones that precede it.

Comment: Thank you for your feed back.. :) I am concentrating mainly on the  split (File, String) function which has to split the parent file into files of size 1 MB. The parent file is getting split, but into many files of sizes much smaller than 1 MB. I do not know why or how this is happening..